# How to store data lake gen2 with Java Functions?

Tags: java, azure-functions

I have Service Bus triggered Java based Azure Function, which should write (json) message to data lake gen 2 storage in CSV or Parquet. Is this possible?

I can find sample code for binary data type for blob. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=java#example

Where I can find sample code or tutorial for data lake?

Comment: Suppose for now this is [not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-supported-azure-services#supported-azure-services). You could use the [java sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-java) to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

I will do with java sdk 
as it seem like no output binding cannot be found.